# Get permission for an SVN folder using SharpSVN

Tags: c#, svn, permissions, sharpsvn

I have have a repository, for example "http://svnserver/repository". Users have different permissions in the folders: "http://svnserver/repository/folder1" or "http://svnserver/folder2". How can I get the permission (read only or read and write) of the user logged in for a specific folder?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check what permissions you have at a certain level?

Comment: I want to check what permissions I have for a specific folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get this using Subversion, except by trying to commit and seeing if you have write access.

I have seen nothing in the protocol or the commands that shows access rights, except for error messages when you don't have access.

Why do you need this?

Comment: I have serialized objects in seperate files. The objects can be edited in my program. I want to set a flag when deserializing so my program knows which objects can be edited and which objects can only be read. Is there a clean solution to force committing a file without changing it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying this:

```
FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
try
{
    f.Demand();
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
}
```

As found on:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10076435/how-to-check-read-write-permission-of-shared-folder-on-network-pc-for-user.aspx

Comment: I am using Subversion, and when I create a local working copy, all folders have read and write permissions.